# How to insert array into object?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, sails.js

I'm building app using SailsJS, AngularJS and MongoDB, I'm confused how to insert data array into object. This is example my schema

**Asset.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema : false,
    attributes: {
        product : { model : 'Product' },
        store   : { model : 'Store' },
        key     : { type : 'object' }
    }
};
```

This is my view form

```
<tbody ng-repeat="attr in product.category.templateAttribute" ng-show="{{product.category.name == 'custom'}}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-small" value="{{attr.attribute}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-small" placeholder="name" ng-model="product.attributes[attr.attribute].name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control input-small" placeholder="add price" ng-model="product.attributes[attr.attribute].additionalPrice" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <file-uploader class="form-control input-small"
                max-size="25000"
                result-model="product.attributes[attr.attribute].file">
            </file-uploader>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the my query

```
ProductCustomAsset.create({
    product     : product.id,
    store       : product.store,
    key         : product.attributes
})
.then(function(){
    next();
})
.catch(function(error){
    next(error);
});
```

What is the problem in my query,no error but value in key only array no object.

I want result to be this

```
{ 
    "_id" : 5,
    "product" : 3,
    "store" : 2
    "key": [
        { 
            "attribute": "xxxxxxx",
            "name": "book",
            "additionaPrice": "xxxx",
            "file": "xxxx" ,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your query should search if exist a product User.findOne("product").exec(function (err, product) {
   product.key.push({ /* whatever */ });
   product.save(function (err) { /* all done */ });
 });    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161056/push-values-into-array-of-mongodb-database-through-sails-js-waterline

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience with AngularJS, why are you referencing 
inputs ng-model with product.attributes?

Have you tried this :

```
<input class="form-control input-small" placeholder="name" ng-model="{{attr.name}}" />
```

like you did :

```
 <input class="form-control input-small" value="{{attr.attribute}}" />
```

And of course deal with rest of product entity in AngularJs way.